# What are the ways to capture keyboard events?

Tags: windows-phone-7

What are the  ways to capture keyboard events? Is there any delegate concept or notification ? I need to capture the keyboard characters when clicked continuously. Please provide me some links to refer.

Comment: I tried to use the Key_Up event of textbox. Although I am able to capture the character but after every click the keyboard is going down, when I again click keyboard comes. I want the keyboard to be there till I click somewhere else. Can any one guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything concrete, but there is the following article on MSDN that talks about responding to [key presses in XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx)

This forum post talks about it in Silverlight, unfortunately the only answer is a [workaround](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/227986/552939.aspx)